# ERROR:could not identify an equality operator for type point

Tags: database, postgresql

I've defined operator = using this code:

```
create operator = (leftarg = point, rightarg = point, procedure = point_eq, commutator = =);
```

However the code below still did not work and raised error like the title, what is wrong?

```
create or replace function skyband_get(dataset text, k integer) 
    returns point[]
as $$
declare 
        rest point[];
        collect point[];
        i integer :=0;
begin
        execute '(select array_agg('||dataset||' order by y DESC,x DESC) from '||dataset||')' into rest;
        while i<k loop
            collect := array_cat(collect,array(select * from skyband_sortedlist(rest)));
            rest := array(select * from(select * from unnest(rest) except select * from unnest(collect)) p);
            i := i + 1;
        end loop;
        return collect;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: A lot of stuff in your function definition is not defined in the question. Can you narrow down which statement causes the error? The usual equality operator for `point` is `~=`, so what is the reason for defining this `=` operator?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Here is the statement caused this error: rest := array(select * from(select * from unnest(rest) except select * from unnest(collect)) p);

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The reason why I defined the operator is that it prompts ERROR:could not identify an equality operator for type point when running that statement above.

Comment: Which statement causes the error? How are `skyband_sortedlist` and the `dataset` defined?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe 'point' is a user-defined type with variable x integer and y integer. The question is, when I try to use 'except' to subtract one unnested array of points from another and re-array the result, the error appears.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To check for equality in a `UNION` or `EXCEPT` clause, PostgreSQL uses the *equality operator* of the type's default *operator class* for the `btree` or the `hash` *access method* (See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xindex.html#XINDEX-OPCLASS) for an explanation of these terms).

The problem is that there is no such operator class for the type `point`.

You can create one yourself. You have to use the `hash` access method because points cannot be ordered in a reasonable fashion.

Apart from an equality operator, a `hash` operator class also needs a hash function for the data type, but it is easy to write one for `point`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.hashpoint(point) RETURNS integer
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
   AS 'SELECT hashfloat8($1[0]) # hashfloat8($1[1])';
```

Now you can define an operator class (you have to be superuser, because such a badly defined operator class can confuse or crash the server):

```
CREATE OPERATOR CLASS public.point_hash_ops DEFAULT FOR TYPE point USING hash AS
   OPERATOR 1 ~=(point,point),
   FUNCTION 1 public.hashpoint(point);
```

Now it should work:

```
VALUES (POINT '(1,1)'), (POINT '(2, 2)')
   EXCEPT
VALUES (POINT '(1,1)');

┌─────────┐
│ column1 │
├─────────┤
│ (2,2)   │
└─────────┘
(1 row)
```